# If you specify a data method the second argument in D3.js, existing elements are undefined

Tags: d3.js

If you specify a data method the second argument in D3.js, existing elements are undefined

```
<div id="hoge">
  <p>C</p>
  <p>A</p>
  <p>Z</p>  
  <p>X</p>
</div>

<script>
dataset = [4,9];
d3.select("#hoge").selectAll("p").data(dataset, function(d,i){
      console.log(d);
      return d;
   })
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .text(function(d){
   return d;
  })
```

console.log

```
UNDEFINED
UNDEFINED
UNDEFINED
UNDEFINED
4
9
```

Why UNDEFINED?
Why not a following?

```
C
A
Z
X
4
9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It still wasn't clear to me when I read the @Ben Lyall answer (sorry Ben, its not you, it's me...) and it's certainly not clear to me from reading the wiki (I think they got it backwards), so I traced through the code to see what's going on...

First of all, it's worth remembering that a `selection` is an array of `groups` and a `group` is an array of **nodes**.  If there is more than one `group`, *the same data is bound to all `groups`*.

When binding data to each `group`, d3 invokes the ***key*** function in two separate phases, first to build an associative array for all the nodes in the group, using the returned value from the ***key*** function as the key and second to derive a key for each data array element.  This is then used to look up the array of nodes and if the look-up succeeds, the data element is bound to its matching node and the node is added to the update selection.

In the first phase the ***key*** is invoked once for every **node** in the `group` with the `this` context set to the **node**.  The `d` argument is the *bound data* on the **node** and the `i` argument is the index of the **node** in the `group`.  The value returned for each **node** and the **node** itself are added to a **collection** of key-value pairs with the node as value and the return value of the ***key*** function as the key.

In the second phase the ***key*** is invoked once for every *element* in the first dimension of the data array with the `this` context set to the data array.  The `d` argument is the *element of the data array* and the `i` argument is the index of the element in the data array.  The value returned is used to look up the collection and if a match is found, that node is put in the update selection.

Hence, as @Ben Lyall said, the `d` in the ***key*** function, in terms of *defining* the keys, is the data previously bound on the node. (d3 adds a `__data__` member on the nodes).  When the key is used to *qualify* data elements, `d` is the data array element.  That's why you see `undefined` for the four nodes and the expected value for the two data elements.

That being said, there is no reason that the key has to be a function of `d`.

Try this...

```
<div id="hoge">
    <p>C</p>
    <p>A</p>
    <p>Z</p>
    <p>X</p>
</div>

<script>
    dataset = [4, 9];
    d3.select("#hoge").selectAll("p").data(dataset, function (d, i) {
        d = d || this.textContent;
        console.log(d);
        return d;
    })
      .enter()
      .append("p")
      .text(function (d) {
          return d;
      })
</script>
```

In phase1, d is the bound data, which is undefined, so the key function returns the text of the nodes.  In phase2, d is the data values so they are returned.  Because none of the keys in phase2 match the ones in phase1, there is no update group.

Just to be perverse, you can also confuse it with this...

```
        d = d || dataset[i];
```

Because the ***key*** function returns the same values for i = 0 and 1 in both phases, the first 2 nodes are considered update nodes and because all of the data is bound according to the ***key*** function, the enter group is empty.

But the most useful case is if you have data like this...

```
dataset = [4, 9, 'X', 'C'];
d3.select("#hoge").selectAll("p").data(dataset, function (d, i) {
    d = d || this.textContent;
    console.log(d);
    return d;
}).attr('class', 'update')
  .enter()
  .append("p").attr('class', 'enter')
  .text(function (d) {
      return d;
  })
```

this is the result...

`<div id="hoge">
        <p class="update">C</p>
        <p>A</p>
        <p>Z</p>
        <p class="update">X</p>
        <p class="enter">4</p>
        <p class="enter">9</p>
</div>`

In phase1, all of the nodes are included in the collection with their text content as key.  In phase2, the data values are used to look up the collection and there is a match on C and X, so they are in the update collection and the numbers, which have no match, are in the enter selection.

Answer (score 1):

Because if you specify a second argument to the `.data` function, the result of that argument will be the value that is bound to the element.  With no second argument, the data is bound by index.  Because you're returning `d`, it will be bound by value.  Since there is no data bound to the existing `p` elements, their data is `undefined`, which doesn't match any values in your `dataset` array, so it therefore treats all the data in your `dataset` array as new values, creating new placeholder `p` elements for them.  The undefined ones will be in the `exit` selection.

See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just use .data(dataset) and then this would bound data to the first two paragraphs. Remaining two elements should be available in .exit(), so you can .remove() them or something else (maybe add some other data to them, like default data).